# what is the difference in the way join is used in python like given below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("-".join("fevicol"));
```

output is:

```
f-e-v-i-c-o-l
```

But:

```
print ("fevicol".join("-"));
```

output is:

```
-
```

Can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: In the latter example, there are no letters to join.Try `print ("fevicol".join("--"));` to see the difference.

Comment: Why would you *expect* the same output?

Answer (score 1):

`'foo'.join('bar')` is equivalent to `str.join('foo', 'bar')`, and means *"put `'foo'` between each of the characters in `'bar'`"*, so will result in:

```
>>> str.join('foo', 'bar')
'bfooafoor'
```

If you switch that around, `str.join('bar', 'foo')` means *"put `'bar'` between each of the characters in `'foo'`"*, so will result in:

```
>>> str.join('bar', 'foo')
'fbarobaro'
```

The `str.join` operation is clearly not commutative: changing the order of the arguments gives a different output.

---

Note also that if there is only one character in the second argument, there are no *"between-character"* places to `put` the first argument, so you just end up with a single character output:

```
>>> str.join('foo', 'b')
'b'
```

If you look at the start and end of the earlier outputs, you can see that the first argument isn't inserted before the first character of the second argument, or after the last character. If the second argument is a single character, that character is both the first and last, so you shouldn't expect the first argument to be inserted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "first".join("second")
'sfirstefirstcfirstofirstnfirstd'
```

It's "put the first string in between each of the character of second string".

If second string is just a character, where to put the first string?? So,

```
>>> "first".join("s")
's'
```

Comment: right with that logic i expect -fevicol if i'm not wrong

Comment: Ha, tell that to guy who provided that API. :P

Comment: before telling him if you can tell me if my logic is right

Comment: I think "-fevicol" (intuitive) should be the output! (Well, a join operation should join stuff)